# Getting an ID of an element from another page and changing attributes value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a HTML page in which I have an `img` element. I also have an `input` field with an `oninput` event. This is what I have problems with. I tested it out my having the svg code inside my HTML document and it works but the problem is that the code is too long and just looks bad.

Either way the function in short takes the value of `this` which is the input value (which is a color) and changes the fill style of the svg id part. The problem I am facing is the fact that the svg file's id can't be found since it is on a different document. Is there a way for me to get an elements id from different page using plain JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<div>
   <img src="male_avatar.svg">
   <span> Background Color: </span>
   <input type="color" value="#ffffff" oninput="changeAvatarColor (this);">
</div>
```

```js
function changeAvatarColor (color) {
    // Some method to take id
    // (svg's id).css({ fill: color.value});
    // P.S the color value is the inputs given color since it's type="color"
}
```

Comment: img element contents cannot be accessed via javascript.

Comment: This didnt work since the img is no where near the input in my actual div!

Comment: Plus its an svg file and i need to change the fill of a specific part...

Comment: @RobertLongson no, I'll defer to you. Deleted my question/comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** 
Make svg code public on GitHub using GutHub Pages and then simply use Ajax and Json to get the code into my document, works perfectly.